# ASP.NET CORE Identity On Load Balanced Partial Logging

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

We have deployed out ASP.NET Core app to a load balanced environment behind an ARR server and we are not using sticky sessions.

We are using cookie authentication.

In the footer of our app we output who the currently authenticated user so we can tell who is authenticated.

When we authenticate the user they are logged in, redirect to the target page and then redirect back to the login page. Once back on the login page we can see that the user has been authenticated because their username is in the footer but they are back on the login page.

If we enable sticky session this problem goes away.

We  thought it might be something to do with data protection keys so we added this:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
 .SetApplicationName("MyApp")
.PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\Keys"));
```

This is taken from :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

but we still have the same problem.

What have configured incorrectly / what else should I investigate?

Comment: The problem was caused because I had accidently swapped
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused because I had accidently swapped around

```
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
```